# Change in columns values when deleting an instance on an recurring event on Android

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-event

does anyone know what columns values changes on the event table when a user deletes one instance of a recurring event?

I have been reading [CalendarContract.EventsColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html) and they talk about recurring events in the beginning, but i can't find more info than that.

I also have been playing with queries to the events table and my result was:

-When i create an event (with any number of instances) i can find one entry on the table for that event.
-When i delete one instance (i have been trying only the last instance of the event) i can find two entries for that event. The first entry is the event that i created in the begin with all the columns values equal to the event created, the second one is a new event for the day of the delete with the deleted value to false.

So anyone have any idea? 
Cheers, Dporem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i guess noone knows...

I have been investigating a bit more and i found this columns:

On Android SDK >= 14 we have:

- [ORIGINAL_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_ID)
- [ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_SYNC_ID)
- [ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME)
- [ORIGINAL_ALL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_ALL_DAY)

On Android SDK < 14 we have:

- [ORIGINAL_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_ID)
- [ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_INSTANCE_TIME)
- [ORIGINAL_ALL_DAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html#ORIGINAL_ALL_DAY)

This columns only change on the second event (this event is created when you delete an instance/entry on the recurring event). On the first event they stay null.